# Orchard CMS and Twitter API Limit - how do you overcome it?

Tags: twitter, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm using the LatestTwitter module on Orchard, which is simple enough to use - you just enter in your twitter handle and you're done. The problem is, as more and more people start to use the site, the tweets suddenly start to disappear on occasion. My guess is that because it's an unauthenticated call, I'm reading the API limit.

Is there a way to overcome this limit? Is there an Orchard Module that has done this? I'm trying to avoid writing a custom Module because I'm quite new to Orchard.

Answer (score 5):

Well there isn't really a way to overcome this, the creator of the widget does say he is caching requests to twitter so it shouldn't really be hurting your limit.

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/01/21/Writing-an-Orchard-widget-LatestTwitter.aspx

Maybe go into the code, debug and make sure it is caching correctly? I have always used the twitter widget made by Wygwam, http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Twitter but I have never used it on a site with a huge amount of traffic :)

Comment: Yes, properly cached, you should never reach the limit.

Comment: So I should increase the cache time? Right now it's 10 minutes. Does this mean that if in an hour, after say 30 minutes the API limit is reached, at the 40 minute mark, my tweets would disappear as it is doing now on my site? So if I make the limit an hour, it should never disappear, correct?

Comment: Well I would have assumed that caching for just 10 minutes would be sufficient as it would cap the max number of times your site could call the API as once every 10 minutes. You could try logging the number of calls it is making to the twitter API?

Comment: Good idea to log, but my skill level isn't quite high enough to understand the code architecture. As for now, I've changed the cache time limit to 60 minutes. From observation, my tweets don't disappear anymore, so my guess is, the minute i hit the api limit, whatever is cached is kept for 60 minutes, and by then the api limit would have reset and allowed me to continue calling it. So this works. I'll update if it doesn't. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've researched, you can't overcome this API Limit for this particular module. However, to stop the tweets from vanishing, I've simply set the cache time limit to 60 minutes. It used to be 10 minutes.

This means that if the API limit is reached, whatever is cached would last for only 10 minutes before the tweets would vanish in the roll up. Making it 60 means it lasts for an hour, more than enough time before the API limit resets and you start loading new tweets.